# How to detect all the text which has an @ sign in a paragraph in php

Tags: php, arrays, regex, laravel-5.1

In my current php project, I'm sending some special texts attached with an @ sign in a paragraph to the back end. I need to detect all the words which has an @ sign and take them as an array. I was trying with the following regex, but its not working, can anyone help me to fix this

```
$text = "my text has some @signs and @names";    
preg_match_all('/(?<!\w)@\w+/', $text, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Comment: it seems that your code is indeed working: https://ideone.com/RvFRSA . if this isn't the expected output, you gotta state what is missing.

Comment: provide a reproducible example along with expected output.

Comment: Please when you ask a regex question, give a sample input and output. Without it we can't test our solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the best solution if your texts are very long, but this will work:

```
$marked = array();
foreach (explode(' ', $text) as $word) {
    if ($word[0] == '@') {
        $marked[] = $word;
    }   
}
```

Will result in:

```
Array
(
    [0] => @signs
    [1] => @names
)
```